# Is there a default assets grouping in order to perform Information Security Risk Assessment?

Tags: risk-management, iso27001

I am working on the implementation of an ISMS and aiming to get 27001 certification. While i was conducting the Risk Assessment, I found it difficult to match all those assets/asset components with all the threats/threat events without making exhaustive and unmanageable lists.

I found many threat lists with their supporting threat events over the internet, but i can not find something similar for assets and asset groups.

Is there a methodology, guideline, etc. that proposes a specific group of assets (e.g. People, 3rd Parties, Hardware, Information, etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific methodology you can do it as per your organization structure,asset distribution, asset usage etc.
However, as per ISO 27002 under clause 8.1.1 mentions that the asset inventory should be made along with ownership and classification (see 8.2) information.
When you look at the 8.2, it mentions that assets can be classified in terms of its legal requirement, its value in organization or process, criticality of asset and sensitivity of asset in terms of information it holds is secured from to unauthorized disclosure or modification.

Based on above classification then it would be easy for you to identify the risk for the assets as it has already been classified in terms of criticality and sensitivity.

Hope above explanation helps.